# Ошибка при создании foreign key в существующей таблице "Failed to open the referenced table 'table_name'" sqalchemy MySQL

Tags: mysql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, foreign-key

Господа, ломаю голову уже третий день. У меня приложение Flask. Есть готовая модель таблицы, которая уже наполнена данными и используется:

```
class Schools(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'schools'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False, unique=True)
```

Я пытаюсь добавить новую модель и связать с таблицей Schools с помощью foreign key
Теперь мои модели выглядят так:

```
class Schools(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'schools'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False, unique=True)
    stud = db.relationship('Students', backref='schools', lazy='dynamic')

class Students(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'students'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    school_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('schools.id'))
```

С помощью Flask-Migrate пытаюсь сделать миграцию и получаю ошибку:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (1824, "Failed to open the referenced table 'schools'")
```

Подскажите, в чем причина?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если таблица точно существует, то есть вероятность, что в качестве движка таблиц используется MyISAM, который не поддерживает внешние ключи. Стоит в качестве движка указать InnoDB

Comment: Да, это и было проблемой. Поменял на InnoDB, все работает

Comment: Спасибо большое